# Classify the singularity of $\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z}$ and $\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z^k}$ where $k$ is an integer greater then or equal to 2

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification, laurent-series, singularity

I was wondering if someone could verify my solution for these two problems. They are based on the textbook *Complex Variables*  by Fisher.

---

Let us start with $\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z}$. We use the fact that $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n/n!$ to obtain:
$$\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z^{2n-1}}{n!} \right) - \frac{1}{z} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n-1}}{n!}$$
Since there are no negative exponents, we conclude that it has a removable singularity.

Similarly, we note that
$$\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z^k} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z^{2n-k}}{n!} \right) - \frac{1}{z^k} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2n-k}}{n!}$$
Now, if $k=2$, we are left with a summation with no negative exponents, hence a removable singularity.

If $k>2$, we are left with negative exponents. Specifically, the largest negative exponent is when $n=1$, and the exponent is thus $2-k$. This means that we have a pole of order $2-k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly done. A minor mistake in the second equation: LHS should be divided by $z^k$ instead of $z$.

Comment: Good catch on the typo. Fixed it

Answer (score 0):

As $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z^2}= 1$ so writing the given function as the product $\frac{e^{z^2}-1}{z^2}.\frac{1}{z^{k-2}}$ the factor $\frac{1}{z^{k-2}}$ is responsible to give a pole of order $k-2$, at $z=0$ where $(k>2)$. In case $k\le2$, this factor is analytic at $z=0$ so the former factor is responsible to give a removable singularity at $z=0$.